# Hotkey to access menu in Gnome

Tags: gnome

In Windows you can access the menu of an application by pressing Alt. From what I read the same is supposed to be true in KDE. However how can I access the Menu via in hotkey when I use Gnome?

Answer (score 3):

Its the same hotkey in both Unity and Gnome-shell

In Unity, press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> to display the Global menu - then press the corresponding shortcut key - for example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

In Gnome-Shell - likewise, use the same key-combination.

[image]